# How to capture screenshot for failed test when using Pytest-bdd and Playwright-Python with non default context

Tags: playwright-python, pytest-bdd

I am using pytest-bdd, Playwright Python, Allure report for my project. Everything works great but the screenshot for failed tests.

Playwright-pytest has screenshot option `--screenshot` but it does not work when using non default context.
https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-pytest/issues/141 
 https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-pytest/issues/111

I wonder whether it is possible to use [pytest-bdd hook](https://pytest-bdd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#hooks) pytest_bdd_step_error() to capture the screen. I cannot find example to pass the `page` variable to pytest_bdd_step_error() to save the screen.

The reason I define context is because my url is https and I have to let the browser to ignore the warning.

Appreciate any suggestion. I am open to not using pytest-bdd if other html report can capture the screenshot and include in the report.

my conftest.py

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def context(browser: Browser):
    context = browser.new_context(ignore_https_errors=True)
    yield context
    context.close()
```